# read variable js in ajax and json

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, ajax

In a .js file I am taking a data and saving it in an input and executing a modal

```
     $('.editCircle').click('click', function () {
                var reclamoIDedit = $(this).attr('data-edit');
                $("#numReclamo").attr("value", reclamoIDedit);
                $("#formUpdate").attr("action", "update.php?idReclamo=" + reclamoIDedit);
                $('#modalEdicion').modal('show');
            });
```

another .js file is responsible for "show data" from my database

```
    var editorReclamo = document.getElementById('editReclamo')
    , loader = document.getElementById('loader');

function cargarEditor() {
    var peticion = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var r = document.getElementById('numReclamo');
    peticion.open('GET', 'edicionExistente.php?reclamo=' + r);
    loader.classList.add('active');
    peticion.onload = function () {
        var datos = JSON.parse(peticion.responseText);
        for (var i = 0; i < datos.length; i++) {
            var elemento = document.createElement('ul');
            elemento.innerHTML += ('<form id="formUpdate" method="POST" action="" autocomplete="off"><input id="numReclamo" name="reclamo" value=""><div class="input-group"><input name="titulo" type="text" class="form-control" id="titulo" aria-describedby="basic-addon3" value="' + datos[i].titulo + '" maxlength="50"><div class="caracteres"> </div></div><div class="input-group" id="responsableID"><input name="responsable" type="text" class="form-control typeahead" id="responsableForm" aria-describedby="basic-addon3" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" value="' + datos[i].responsable + '"> </div><div class="input-group" id="descripcionID"><textarea name="descripcion" class="form-control" aria-label="With textarea"  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Deja claro la importancia y los beneficios para la comunidad la resolucion del problema">' + datos[i].descripcion + '</textarea></div><div class="modal-footer"><button type="Submit" class="btn btn-primary enviarReclamo btnGuardar"> Guardar!</button></div></form>');
            editorReclamo.appendChild(elemento);
        }
    }
    peticion.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (peticion.readyState == 4 && peticion.status == 200) {
            loader.classList.remove('active');
        }
    }
    peticion.send();
    $('.editCircle').click('click', function () {
        cargarEditor();
    });
```

the url where he reads everything would be: edicionExistente.php

```
<?php

error_reporting(0);
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
include "db.php";

$var = $_GET['reclamo'];
$db->set_charset("ut8");
$reclamos = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT  * FROM `reclamos` WHERE id_reclamo= $var ");

$propuestas = [];
while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($reclamos)) {
    $usuario = [
        'id_propuesta' => $fila['id_reclamo'],
        'titulo' => $fila['titulo'],
        'responsable' => $fila['responsable'],
        'descripcion' => $fila['descripcion'],
        'imagen' => $fila['file_name'],

    ];
    array_push($propuestas, $usuario);
}
echo json_encode($propuestas);

?>
```

my question is, I understand that the problem is that it does not "change" or does not read the variable "r", which is where I send the number to filter on the dat database....

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: If you would like us to answer a question, you need to ask it. We do not have time to figure out what problem you might be having or what outcome you are trying to achieve. We would love to help you, but we need to know more.

Comment: I understand that the problem is that it does not "change" or does not read the variable "r", which is where I send the number to filter on the dat database....

Comment: If you understand the problem, then what are you asking us to solve?

Comment: I do not know how to fix it

Comment: What do you want `r` to be? `document.getElementById('numReclamo');` will return a DOM element, which does not make much sense to send in GET. **WHAT** do you want the code to do?

Comment: You are sending a DOM element instead of its text content... `var r = document.getElementById('numReclamo');`... puede que `peticion.open('GET', 'edicionExistente.php?reclamo=' + $(r).text);` funcione mejor...

Comment: When I click on ".editCircle" a variable "claimIDedit" is created, obtained from a "data-edit" label.
I'm interested in the value saved in "reclamadoIDedit". Since this value I want to send as a parameter by GET to then transform it into a php variable and read it in "EditingExistent.php". I take this variable with $ _GET and replace it with "$ claims" to later use it in the SELECT.
When I do it manually, that is, instead of replacing the variable "$ claims" with $ _GET ["claims"], I only put an X number works, but the way with GET does not take anything

Comment: @TomasFranciscoFirbeda  como Tomal te respondio debes usar document.getElementById('numReclamo').value en vez de document.getElementById('numReclamo') saludos

Comment: Thank you all for taking your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't comment. But us said above in comments `document.getElementById('numReclamo')` won't give you a string which i suppose you would like to pass in your GET.

Maybe you should try `document.getElementById('numReclamo').value` ? Is that what u need? You will get a value from that DOM element ( like input or sth).